Spring Boot - Uploading a file with object and a lot of text(5000 char or more)?
The goal is to allow user to fill out a form with:

basic info(small text fields)
a text area(large amount of text, think one pager of text)
and upload a file

Surprisingly, I've never built any API like this. It's always been file with a few smaller fields, json only, or file only.
Ex, this works as expected:
@PutMapping(value = "/submit", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<FormData> submit(
    @RequestParam(required = false) String firstName,
    @RequestParam(required = false) String lastName,
    @RequestParam(required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate submitDate,
    @RequestParam(required = false) MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

For the text area, I would change to:
@PutMapping(value = "/submit", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<FormData> submit(
    @RequestParam(required = false) String firstName,
    @RequestParam(required = false) String lastName,
    @RequestParam(required = false) String explanation, // possibly 5-10k characters
    @RequestParam(required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate submitDate,
    @RequestParam(required = false) MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

The result is header too large error.
Then I switched to @RequestBody:
@PutMapping(value = "/submit", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<FormData> submit(
    @RequestBody Submission submission) throws IOException {

Submission would have the same fields with the 'explanation'. I would get 'Media not supported' error.
So far, I've not found any examples like my usecase. Any guidance is appreciated.
I have alternative solution where I 'convert' the explanation textarea content into a file, then I would end up with an API that accepts a few small text fields, and two files. But I don't think that's best practice.

Are you sending in the Submission as JSON?  Do you just need to specify that it consumes JSON? consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE

Why not put the file base64-encoded into the json-Object with all the data. Or:
Years ago some guy solved this by making two request, one file-upload returning a handle to the cached file and the second with the handle as form-field

@Turo, yes that's also my other solution, which i actually done before. but that was like 201x. and since im moving to spring, i thought there'd be some other solution.

@Tristan ive tried many choices, like json/media/applcation/octet stream etc.. just errors..

As I understand, you're trying to handle a multipart file as well. Have you tried using @RequestPart? It allows you to separate the multipart file from the JSON object and handle it as a separate parameter.
I think, handling both a multipart file and JSON payload together isn't natively supported in Spring, as @RequestBody is designed to handle a single, serialized JSON object in the request body.
@PutMapping(value = "/submit", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public ResponseEntity<FormData> submit(
@RequestPart Submission submission, @RequestPart MultipartFile file) throws IOException {}

